# How to send data to REST api in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to send `basic auth header` to Paypal api but can not get the format right. I read somewhere that I have to `Base64` encode the credentials but that does'nt worked well and no response is generated.  Here is the request I would like to send to REST API

```
var options = {
url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
method: 'POST',
headers: 'application/json',
auth: {
    'user': 'XXXXXX',
    'pass': 'YYYYYY'
}}
```

Sample request in curl which I wish to send in javascript

[Paypal get access token api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token)

under the heading `POSTMAN`

What will be correct structure to send this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `:` thing now I can get the correct Base64 value and concatenate to authorization header and its working fine